# Xpath in XSD C#

Tags: c#, xpath, xsd

I have an XSD file such as:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="...">
 <xs: import namespace="...">
<xs: import namespace="...">
<xs: import namespace="...">
<xs:element name="FSM">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<Info>
<ID> 44</ID>
<Priority>3</Priority>
</Info>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</schema>
```

I hvae more them one "xs:element" in the schema,but it's just an example...
I can't get the FSM node. I tried

```
`xDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"//FSM");`
```

(xDoc is XMLDocument) but I got null. I tried the xpath @"//*[name()=FSM" and i got null. What the xPath to get the FSM element. I want something generic so i could find it wherever it is in all the elements in the XSD. P.S I can only use .Net 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply XPath to the schema itself then you need a path like `//xs:element[@name = 'FSM']`.

Comment: Not working. It tells me i need namespace manager... and it's not working with it either.

Comment: Yes, of course you need a namespace manager: `XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable); mgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"); XmlNode n = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//xs:element[@name = 'FSM']", mgr);`.

Comment: I got the node, but for some reason his name is "xs:element". How can i get to the 'FSM' string?

Comment: Got it! to get to the string the code is:node.Attributes[0].Value

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to add the `xs` namespace to the xpath statement.

Comment: No. It's tell me that a namespace manager is needed, and when i give him such it's not working either...